# Creating a SQL view with transformation and join (??)

Tags: sql

I'm not a *complete* stranger to SQL, but I normally do embedded programming, so I'm struggling with this specific problem and don't know how to approach it or what to ask google.

I've created a picture that visualizes my problem. On the left you see the main SQL table that I want to retrieve data from (in order to automatically generate a CSV, which so far worked very well).

I need the data "reformatted" though - I want to create a VIEW that is formatted like on the right. I only need specific ValueIDs, in a specific time  (`WHERE TIMESTAMP between 'xx-xx-xx' and 'yy-yy-yy'`).

The timestamps for each "ValueID-block" are absolute identical to the millisecond.

Thanks so much in advance!

[image: problem visualization]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select timestamp,
       max(case when valueid = 2 then value end) as value_2,
       max(case when valueid = 3 then value end) as value_3,
       max(case when valueid = 5 then value end) as value_5,
       max(case when valueid = 7 then value end) as value_7
from t
group by timestamp;
```

EDIT:

If you only want timestamps that have all four values you can add a `having` clause:

```
select timestamp,
       max(case when valueid = 2 then value end) as value_2,
       max(case when valueid = 3 then value end) as value_3,
       max(case when valueid = 5 then value end) as value_5,
       max(case when valueid = 7 then value end) as value_7
from t
group by timestamp
having sum(case when valueid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when valueid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when valueid = 5 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when valueid = 7 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sadly I oversimplified my Image. There are more  Timestamps in there, then those connected to my vaule_id's - hence I get lots of "NULL" Values as well.

https://pasteboard.co/IPVBzsu.png

Comment: This looks and works like black sorcery!!

I'm afraid and amazed.

AWESOME!!



One more thing: could I also order it by timestamp?

Comment: just add ORDER BY timestamp ASC; before the ";" - LOL. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is pivot (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

An example, sorry for the dirty code...

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT '2020-01-01 12:00' AS 'time', '1' as 'ValueID', '0,0' AS 'val'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-01-01 12:00' AS 'time', '2' as 'ValueID', '0,1' AS 'val'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-01-01 12:00' AS 'time', '3' as 'ValueID', '0,2' AS 'val'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-01-01 12:00' AS 'time', '4' as 'ValueID', '0,3' AS 'val'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-01-01 12:00' AS 'time', '5' as 'ValueID', '0,4' AS 'val'
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
PIVOT
(
MAX(val)
for valueid IN
([1], [2], [3], [4], [5] ) -- just remove from here the values you don't want or in the view
) AS  pvt
```

I would make the view creating a pivot on the whole table and control in the select.